# Ruby: implicit block iterator

Tags: ruby, iterator, block

Is there a way to do this?
instead of:

```
links.each do |link|
  link.color "red"
end
```

make the iterator (between | |) implicit like so:

```
links.each do
  color "red"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that this is not possible.  You can however [instance_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-instance_eval) each element, but **I certainly wouldn't recommend it without good reason**

```
foo = ["test","test2","foo","bar","foobar"]

foo.each do |f|
  f.instance_eval do
    p reverse
  end
end
```

Comment: -1 for using `instance_eval`, +1 for the bold warning. Net zero. But then +1 for the idea. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is worth the effort in this instance (and it adds unnecessary complexity) but it's nice to know that you can do something like the following:

```
proc = Proc.new { |i| i.color 'red' }
links.map(&proc)
```